# Camera2api crash on some device while recording video/

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-mediarecorder

For record video using camera2 api setup media recorder and for highest possible 16:9 ratio preview size , it work on smaller number device without crash but other device it crash on `createCaptureSession()` method, not sure if media recorder failed for possible  preview size ,Media recorder set up using following method

```
profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);

  mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(profile.audioCodec);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioChannels(profile.audioChannels);
```

This work on some device without crash and work on all device if output size is equal or less than 1920p ,
But for high resolutuion video size crash on `createCaptureSession()` with following error

```
`Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Surface was abandoned
android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize (SurfaceUtils.java:84)
android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init> (OutputConfiguration.java:281)
android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init> (OutputConfiguration.java:145)
android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession (CameraDeviceImpl.java:513)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity.startPreview (CameraActivity.java:370)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity.access$200 (CameraActivity.java:71)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity$1.onOpened (CameraActivity.java:641)
android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run (CameraDeviceImpl.java:148)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7258)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
Caused by android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils$BufferQueueAbandonedException
android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils.throwOnError (LegacyExceptionUtils.java:73)
android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceSize (LegacyCameraDevice.java:606)
android.hardware.camera2.utils.SurfaceUtils.getSurfaceSize (SurfaceUtils.java:82)
android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init> (OutputConfiguration.java:281)
android.hardware.camera2.params.OutputConfiguration.<init> (OutputConfiguration.java:145)
android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession (CameraDeviceImpl.java:513)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity.startPreview (CameraActivity.java:370)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity.access$200 (CameraActivity.java:71)
com.corepix.Teleprompter.Activity.CameraActivity$1.onOpened (CameraActivity.java:641)
android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$1.run (CameraDeviceImpl.java:148)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:216)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7258)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

`

Comment: please post complete logcat trace here

Comment: @Quicklearner check this logcat.